# android layout in virtual device is not the same as in layout preview and real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

environment:  
Android Studio 3.4.1 
activity_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in android studio layout design tab, it displays as below.
[image]

> my real phone device profile : 
>   `resolution: 1440x720 px` 
>   `screen size: 5.45 inch` 
>   `android version: 8.1.0`

it displays normally in a real device

[image]

> While in android studio virtual device EditText's hint message is not completely displayed.
>   `virtual device profile:`
>   `resoluton: 480x800` 
>   `density: hdpi` 
>   `API: 26` 
>   `Target:Android 8.0(Google APIs)` 
>   `Size: 4.0 inch`

[image]

Comment: can you give me your full layout code ??

Comment: Isn't it obvious? There is not enough space for the entire EditText hence the partial view. The screen size and density of your virtual device is too small.

Comment: @BlackBlind , not I add the full layout code

Comment: @Venus try my answer it will fit in your all requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the LinearLayout instead of ConstraintLayout. It will solve your problem easily.

**Code**

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:hint="Enter a message"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:text="Button"/>
```